# Javascript global variables and references to them and their parts

Tags: javascript

I'm writing little snippets to learn more about using Javascript with API's, and have stumbled onto another problem I can't figure out on my own. I have a global variable (object?) "coins", read in from the API, and its' data field "symbol". I can use "symbol" to reference the data held there, in part of my code, without any errors. Later in the code, I use it again, and I get an error about it being undefined, despite the fact that the values returned from using it, are both defined, and, what I expected. While we are at it, maybe someone can tell me why I assign values to global variables (declared outside of all of the functions), but the variables when called, are "undefined". To see it in action, visit www.mattox.space/XCR and open up dev tools.

```
            /*

    FLOW:
    get ALL coins, store NAME and SYMBOL into an object.
    loop over the names object comparing to $SYMBOL text from form, return the NAME when found.
    hit the API again, with the $NAME added to the URL.
    create a table row.
    insert data from second API hit, into table row
    SOMEWHERE in there, do the USD conversion from BTC.
    */

    //var name = getName();
    var bitcoinValue = 0;
    var coins = new Array;
    var form = ""; // Value pulled from the form
    var symbol = ""; // "id" on the table
    var id = ""; // value pulled from the table at coins[i].id matched to coins[i].symbol

    var formSym = "";
    var formUSD = 0;
    var formBTC = 0;
    var form24h = 0;

    function run() {
      getFormData();
      allTheCoins("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/");
      testGlobal();
    }


    function testGlobal() {
      console.log("These are hopefully the values of the global variables");
      console.log(formSym + " testGlobal");
      console.log(formUSD + " testGlobal");
      console.log(formBTC + " testGlobal");
      console.log(form24h + " testGlobal");
    }

    function getFormData(){ //This function works GREAT!
      form = document.getElementById("symbol").value //THIS WORKS
      form = form.toUpperCase(); //THIS WORKS
    }

    function allTheCoins(URL) {
      var tickerRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      tickerRequest.open('GET', URL);
      tickerRequest.send();
      tickerRequest.onload = function() {
        if (tickerRequest.status >= 200 && tickerRequest.status < 400) {
          var input = JSON.parse(tickerRequest.responseText);
          for(var i in input)
          coins.push(input[i]);
          testFunction(coins);
        }
        else {
          console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
        }
        console.log(formSym + " allTheCoins!"); // NOPE NOPE NOPE
        console.log(formUSD) + " allTheCoins!"; // NOPE NOPE NOPE
        console.log(formBTC + " allTheCoins!"); // NOPE NOPE NOPE
        console.log(form24h + " allTheCoins!"); // NOPE NOPE NOPE
      }
    }

    function testFunction(coins) {
      for (var i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {

        if (coins[i].symbol == form) { // But right here, I get an error.
          formSym = coins[i].name;
          formUSD = coins[i].price_usd;
          formBTC = coins[i].price_btc;
          form24h = coins[i].percent_change_24h;
          console.log(formSym + " testFunction");
          console.log(formUSD + " testFunction");
          console.log(formBTC + " testFunction");
          console.log(form24h + " testFunction");
          //DO EVERYTHING RIGHT HERE! On second thought, no, this needs fixed.
        }
        else if (i > coins.length) {
          formSym = "Error";
          formUSD = 0;
          formBTC = 0;
          form24h = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    /*

    if (24h >= 0) {
    colorRED
    }
    else {
    colorGreen
    }

    */
```

Comment: `coins[i]` is `undefined` because you iterated past the end of the array. That causes an error when you try to access `coins[i].symbol`. Change your loop condition in `testFunction` from `i < (coins.length + 1)` to just `i < coins.length`.

Comment: There's lots of code here. Can you simplify it to just the parts that are relevant to your question, and remove all the commented-out code?

Comment: I fixed the code above to be more readable but I'm going to delete this post unless there is an objection. Removing that "+ 1" helped, but the biggest problem is that the values I'm trying to call aren't "ready yet" from the xhr. I need to learn either callbacks or promises (can't quite wrap my head around that. Thank you both for not simply down-voting and moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a possible way of doing it that you can get inspired by. its based on a httpRequest promise that set the headers and method.

```
    let allTheCoins = obj => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(obj.method || obj.method, obj.url);
        if (obj.headers) {
            Object.keys(obj.headers).forEach(key => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(key, obj.headers[key]);
            });
        }
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
        xhr.send(obj.body);
    });
};

allTheCoins({
    url: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"}
})
        .then(data => {
            ParseCoins(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
        });

function ParseCoins(data) {
    const coins = JSON.parse(data);
    const form = getFormVal();/*retrieve form val*/
    const id = getTableId(); /*retrieve table id*/
    const bitcoinValue = getBitcoinVal();/*retrieve bitcoin Value*/
    const final_result = [];
    for (let i = 0, len = coins[0].length; i < len; i++) {
        const coin = coins[0][i];
        for (let ii in coin) {
            if (coin.hasOwnProperty(ii)) {
                if (coin[ii].symbol == form) {
                    let element = {
                        formSym: coin[ii].name,
                        formUSD: coin[ii].price_usd,
                        formBTC: coin[ii].price_btc,
                        form24h: coin[ii].percent_change_24h
                    };
                    final_result.push(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    coontinueElseWhere(final_result);
}
```

Comment: I'll test this code when I get home, and hopefully mark it as the answer!

Comment: Might have a glitch depending on the API response (object or array ?). Pushing into coins array might be redondant...

Comment: It returns an object, well, 956 objects, in an array.

Comment: in this case you can simplify even more and avoid the push. I have updated the code.